# How can I allow a Cordova 6.1 app to embed an iframe in iOS from a website?

Tags: ios, cordova, iframe, ionic-framework, mobile-safari

Until I recently built, my cordova app was able to embed an iframe of a website just fine; now, presumably after an update I forgot about, building the app results in the iframe being blank on iOS but works in Android.

I have added the following settings to config.xml:

`<access origin="*"/>
  <access origin="*.pushwoosh.com" />
  <access origin="*.hoby.org" />
  <allow-navigation href="*" />
  <allow-intent href="*" />`

As well as the following Content Security Policy:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">`

Which should allow basically everything. I have the cordova-whitelist plugin added, using cordova 6.1.0 and Ionic 1.7.14

Edit: it actually works on iOS emulator but not when I run it on the device.

Edit 2: it seems like it may be a mobile safari issue; I am viewing the files over my network and even outside of Cordova they're not loading properly. I can confirm though that this was working as of a few days ago at least.

Comment: Are you aware that Phonegap is not a [webserver or a webbrowser](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#005)? Are you aware that both [Google and Apple frown on apps](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#005a) that are website wrappers?

Comment: I'm aware that it's not a webserver or a browser; and I'm aware that they are frowned upon. What clients demand, however, is often not particularly in line with reality.

Comment: Okay. Make sure you get the money first, because you likely won't get into the App "stores". You'll have your answer in a bit. Best of Luck.

Comment: Note part of the answer will be for people reading this in the future.

Comment: probably related issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-10709

Answer (score 26, accepted):

your application of the `whitelist` plugin is close, but likely is failing because you have javascript in your index.html. `CSP` has stopped many developers. The easiest thing to do is move all the Javascript and CSS to their own separate files.

Short of that, here is a widely applied solution:

As a side note, the `whitelist` system is required as of [Cordova Tools 5.0.0](http://cordova.apache.org/news/2015/04/21/tools-release.html) (April 21, 2015). For *Phonegap Build*, that means since [`cli-5.1.1`](http://phonegap.com/blog/2015/06/16/phonegap-updated-on-build/) (16 Jun 2015)

Add this to your `config.xml`

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist"      source="npm" spec="1.1.0" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
<access origin="*" /> <!-- Required for iOS9 -->
```

**NOTE YOUR APP IS NOW INSECURE. IT IS UP TO YOU TO SECURE YOUR APP.**
Add the following to your `index.html`

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
         content="default-src *; 
                  style-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; 
                  script-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';">
```

**NOTE YOUR APP IS NOW INSECURE. IT IS UP TO YOU TO SECURE YOUR APP.**
This *whitelist* worksheet should help.
[HOW TO apply the Cordova/Phonegap the whitelist system](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/the-whitelist-system.md)

Comment: "NOTE YOUR APP IS NOW INSECURE". Can you explain a bit what exactly is the security risk encoutered?

Comment: Insecurity can mean a lot of things in computers. If my app have strict control of content displayed in html file, and my app code prevent opening external links with JS, is it still risky to use wildcard? What bad thing could happen exactly? any example?

Comment: Honnestly I don't understand at all why you are so rude... Yes I'm not very experienced with security of Cordova apps... and then what? I don't deserve do become better? Maybe the bad programmer is the one that is too proud to share its own knowledge...

Comment: I think he is kindly asking you to read the Link he posted HOW TO: reading that will give you all the answers u need

Comment: @IanWarner The real answer is it has nothing to do with the original question. So it deserves no answer. Taking the question off-topic is frowned upon and should be strongly discouraged. To be clear, this is not just on Stackoverflow, but all Q&A forums. I will not comment on the laziness indicated.

Comment: Agreed but maybe he just never saw the link :)

Comment: @IanWarner this was an attempt to take the question off-topic. As you will see, I have a decent score for my profile. I'm still getting a hundred or so points a month without answering questions. I believe this is because I resist taking the question off-topic. It is not easy. Sometimes you have to be rude.

Comment: Hmmm. This didnt work for me: `SecurityError (DOM Exception 18): The operation is insecure.`