# ionic embedded youtube video stopped playing on iOS

Tags: ios, video, ionic-framework

I have a published app which up until a few weeks ago was playing embedded youtube video's just fine, now all that appears is a plain black screen.
Works fine on web and android, but not on iPhones.

Here is an example link:

https://www.youtube.com/embed/DD7SgzW-6Qs

this is the code

```
        <div class="video-container" *ngIf="videoURL!=''">
        <iframe [src]="videoURL" autoplay="false" autostart="false" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is to add this to the config.xml

```
    <allow-navigation href="*://*.youtube.com/*" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this and things worked fine for me

```
.config(function ($sceDelegateProvider) {
    $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist(['self', new RegExp('^(http[s]?):\/\/(w{3}.)?youtube\.com/.+$')]);
});
```

Comment: Can you provide more information on how and where to use that function?

Comment: In app.js for example but you can insert it anywhere

Comment: I think this code is for ionic v1, can someone post a solution for ionic v2?

Comment: Have you see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36318185/how-can-i-allow-a-cordova-6-1-app-to-embed-an-iframe-in-ios-from-a-website/36440562#36440562