# iFrame block not showing up in the iPhone

Tags: ios, css, iframe, sass, mendix

I have a hybrid mobile app in Mendix. In one page of the app, I am displaying some data with text and also video or website URL embedded.

```
<iframe id="quizWidget-454107" width="100%" height="900px" frameborder="0" border="none" src="https://www.qzzr.com/widget/quiz/fi9xdWl6emVzLzQ1NDEwNw"></iframe>
```

Here we are embedding this website, and we also embed youtube URL here.

The issue is, this embedded URL(video/website) shows up in a section on Android phone but not in iPhone. May be Safari does not render iFrame correctly.

Any idea what we can replace iFrame with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please see an answer to a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36440562/1513051). I believe You need to add `<meta>` tags to your index.html page to allow the app to load external content, preferable using a Content Security Policy (CSP).